# layout "resource not found" exception while trying to switch to tabbed fragment activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a loginActivity with a submit button that has sendMessage() for onClick and when I try to run the application on emulator, I get caused by: resource not found which is the resource of the layout of my 2nd activity.
Any help would be appreciated. I've tried to delete R.java and rebuild but that' doesn't help.

loginActivity

```
public class Login extends Activity {
    public final static String USERNAME = "com.example.seattleivg.USERNAME";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TabActionBarHomeActivity.class);
        //get username from usernameText field
        //EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameText);
        //String message = editText.getText().toString();
        //key-value pair to pass between activities
        //intent.putExtra(USERNAME, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.seattleivf"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.seattleivf.Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.seattleivf.TabActionBarHomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.seattleivf.Login">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.seattleivf.Login"/>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

TabActionBarHomeActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_action_bar_home);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        //Make sure we're running on HoneyComb or higher to user ActionBar APIs
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

            //show the Up button in the action bar.
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

            String label1 = getResources().getString(R.string.label1);
            Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
            tab.setText(label1);
            TabListener<AndrologyHomeFragment> tl = new TabListener<AndrologyHomeFragment>(
                    this, label1, AndrologyHomeFragment.class);
            tab.setTabListener(tl);
            actionBar.addTab(tab);

            String label2 = getResources().getString(R.string.label2);
            tab = actionBar.newTab();
            tab.setText(label2);
            TabListener<EmbryologyHomeFragment> tl2 = new TabListener<EmbryologyHomeFragment>(
                    this, label2, EmbryologyHomeFragment.class);
            tab.setTabListener(tl2);
            actionBar.addTab(tab);
        }
      //tried added here too
      //setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_action_bar_home);
    }
```

activity_tab_action_bar_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".TabActionBarHomeActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

R.java

```
public static final class layout {
    public static final int activity_login=0x7f030000;
    public static final int activity_tab_action_bar_home=0x7f030001;
    public static final int andrology_home=0x7f030002;
    public static final int embryology_home=0x7f030003;
}
```

**Updated the LogCat files after clean project**

```
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.seattleivf/com.example.seattleivf.TabActionBarHomeActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030001
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030001
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1013)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2098)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:852)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.example.seattleivf.TabActionBarHomeActivity.onCreate(TabActionBarHomeActivity.java:53)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
05-01 15:30:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  ... 11 more
```

Edit
AndrologyHomeFragment.java (EmbryologyHomeFragment.java is the same with respective xml)

```
public class AndrologyHomeFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.andrology_home, container, false);
    }
}
```

andrology_home.xml (embryology_home.xml is the same)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/andrology_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="andrology layout" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where are you setting the content view for your second activity ? I don't see setContentView(layout) being called in your second activity.

Comment: Just added it, still getting the same error. Thanks for pointing it out, it's my first android app

Comment: The exception is in your EmbryologyHomeFragment and not the activity. The fragment is creating a view too as it seems. That's where the exception is thrown. So you need to post the EmbryologyHomeFragment code and the related layout (if there's any)

Comment: plz also add AndrologyHomeFragment class code because problem is inside AndrologyHomeFragment instead of code shared by you.Thanks

Comment: I've posted the code. Embryology and Andrology are both the same code except linking to separate xml files

Comment: If you are using eclipse, restart eclipse and try doing a clean build.

Comment: @deepdroid I restarted and cleaned the project but app is still crashing. I updated the LogCat file, the error now appears to be in activity_tab_action_bar.xml (the resource id). Does it matter that my layout files are in **layout-land folder??**

Comment: move that to layout folder and check.

Comment: If they are in layout-land and you start the app in portrait mode it will crash

Comment: I moved the files to layout and that worked great. So ALL the layout files have to be in layout-land for it to work in landscape? Can you post as answer so that I can accept?

Comment: @Sara You only need to provide alternative resources if you want them to differ based on some qualifiers. For instance, if you want to define a different layout for landscape, you can provide an alternative layout resource in the `layout-land` folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So based on the discussions happened on this thread the issue was that the layout resources were placed in a wrong folder, here is the part in the developer site that explains how to provide resources for specific device configurations.

[AlternativeResources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)